# MySQL Row-Based Replication (RBR) - Log file containing unexpected statement

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I just configure 2 mySQL servers for a MASTER-MASTER replication.
I choose the RBR replication for some reason.

My congifuration on the server **ONE** :

```
#replication
server-id=1
binlog_do_db = db1
binlog_ignore_db = db2
log-bin="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/my56"
auto_increment_increment = 2
auto_increment_offset = 1
binlog_format=ROW
replicate_do_db=db1
```

and on the server **TWO** :

```
#replication
server-id=2
binlog_do_db = db1
log-bin="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/my56"
auto_increment_increment = 2
auto_increment_offset = 2
binlog_format=ROW
replicate_do_db=db1
```

With this, the replication works.

For example, on server **ONE**, if I execute :

```
USE db1;
INSERT INTO db1.table1 values (foo,bar);
```

It's works on the server TWO.

If on server **ONE** I execute :

```
USE db1;
INSERT INTO second_db.table2 values (foo,bar);
```

The insert is not execute on the server **TWO**, it's good.

If on server **ONE** I execute :

```
CREATE table db1.tableFoo(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

The create table is not execute on the server **TWO**, it's good because I choose the Row-Based replication, so I have to manualy execute the CREATE STATEMENT on server **TWO**. It's what I want.

**Now, there is my problem :**

If on the server **ONE** I execute :

```
USE db1;
CREATE table db1.tableFoo(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

The CREATE TABLE is execute on the server **TWO**, it's **NOT** good ! Normally with the Row-Based Replication the CREATE ORDER is not replicated.

Worst, if after the *USE db1;* if create a table in another database, the CREATE TABLE is replicated on my server **TWO**, and my slave is aborted on the server **TWO** because de database doesn't exist...

Do you have any idea ? I dont want any CREATE / ALTER / CREATE USER ... send to my replication even if I use à **USE db1;**

I based my work on the mySQL documentation, especially this one : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html

Thank you and merry Xmas !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDL statements are *always* logged using statement-based replication, regardless of whether you've chosen RBR or not. As a result, the default (current) database *is important* when you execute `CREATE TABLE` statements.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db :

> DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE are always logged as statements, without regard to the logging format in effect, so the following statement-based rules for --binlog-do-db always apply in determining whether or not the statement is logged.
>
> ...Only those statements are written to the binary log where the default database (that is, the one selected by USE) is db_name.

This suggests that the behavior you observe is expected, although it is a bit odd.

If possible, I'd suggest that you `USE` an unreplicated DB (for example `mysql`) before executing DDL that you do not want to replicate in your application.

Comment: +1 although it's not really odd at all... combining `replicate_do_db=db1` with `use db1` this is exactly the expected behavior.  [replicate-wild-do-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-do-table) is probably a better choice than `replicate-do-db`, although doing anything other than "replicate everything" is usually a recipe for trouble.

Comment: Ok thank you! I think my english is not very good, and I misunderstand this sentence. :/